# Those Columns are out of bound error at autoResizeColumns method

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, add-on

I have **2D array data** to **add** to the **sheet**. I have a script that will add **columns** in the Google app script. I used the **setValue** method for **adding** data in the Google sheet. I had data of **length 784** to add to the sheet. After that, I'm trying to **resize** the **column** as per the **text**. When I have data of **length 500** at that time **autoSizeColumns** method works **fine** but when I had data of **length 784** at that time it's showing the error **"Those columns are out of bounds"**. I don't know why this error is coming. The script working fine for **printing** data to the sheet but at **resizeColumns** it's giving an error.

Code for **adding** data into sheet.

```
  const lastRow = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getLastRow();
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(lastRow + 1, 1, arr.length, arr[0].length).setValues(arr);

  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().autoResizeColumns(1, arr.length);
```

Can anyone Guide me on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The arguments of `autoResizeColumns(startColumn, numColumns)` are `startColumn, numColumns`. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#autoresizecolumnsstartcolumn,-numcolumns) In your script, it seems that you are using it as follows.

```
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().autoResizeColumns(1, arr.length);
```

If `arr` is `2D array data` of `I have 2D array data to add to the sheet.` and `data of length 784` is the number of rows, `startColumn` and `numColumns` of `autoResizeColumns(startColumn, numColumns)` are `1` and `784`, respectively. When the maximum column in your active sheet is less than 784, an error like `Exception: Those columns are out of bounds.` occurs. I thought that this might be the reason for your current issue of `When I have data of length 500 at that time autoSizeColumns method works fine but when I had data of length 784 at that time it's showing the error "Those columns are out of bounds".`.

For example, if you want to avoid the error, how about the following modification? In this modification, the maximum column is used as `numColumns`.

```
const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
const lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
sheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, 1, arr.length, arr[0].length).setValues(arr);
sheet.autoResizeColumns(1, sheet.getMaxColumns());
```

Or, if you are required to use `arr.length` as `numColumns`, how about the following modification?

```
const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
const lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
sheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, 1, arr.length, arr[0].length).setValues(arr);
const maxColumn = sheet.getMaxColumns();
const arrLength = arr.length;
if (arrLength <= maxColumn) {
  sheet.autoResizeColumns(1, arrLength);
} else {
  sheet.insertColumnsAfter(maxColumn, arrLength - maxColumn).autoResizeColumns(1, arrLength);
}
```

#### Reference:

- [autoResizeColumns(startColumn, numColumns)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#autoresizecolumnsstartcolumn,-numcolumns)